# Is there a need to display arrows in the drop-down fields in the mobile application?

Tags: mobile-application, dropdown

We build a simple mobile app form with 2 drop-down fields and one text input field for iOS and Android platform.

My question is should we definitely use a small arrow icon at the end of field that designed as drop-down for use one of several values for better UX scenario? Seems that this arrow eats up some space for placeholder of value that can be choose.

Is there any useful use at all for using the arrow for the drop-down fields in a mobile application, given the small screen size of some devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must avoid confusing the user. A button must look like a button, an input field must look like an input field and a select/dropdown field must look like a select/dropdown field.

**Unless you create a design template for the dropdown that make the looks like a dropdown than this, please, do not consider to replace.**

[image]

As a user, a field without an arrow will look like an input field to me.

**BUT**, if your dropdown will work like a search box (autocomplete) that shows options when I type then you should make obvious that the user should type something to find an option and I only recommend this option if you have a lot of options inside the select field.

*P.S.: The name of one of the most famous UX books is "Don't Make Me Think" and you should consider this for your users.*